# using .gitignore some files are actually ignored while some other not

Tags: git, github

My project is structure such as

```
root
  .gitignore
  -src
   - config.ts
  -dist
   - config.js
```

I have a `.gitignore` file like this (I am showing just the first 2 lines)

```
config.ts
config.js
```

What I see is that `config.ts` (present the **src** folder) is actually ignored and not saved on git while `config.js` (present in the **dist** folder) is NOT ignored ans is actually saved on git.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all ignore files form git cache and push it to origin, follow these command:

```
 git rm -r --cached . 
 git add .
 git commit -m 'Removed all files that are in the .gitignore' 
 git push origin master
```

Your *.gitignore* file like this:

```
dist/config.js
```

Answer (score 1):

`config.js` was probably already tracked by git and should be untracked first:

```
git rm dist/config.js
```